# Autofac register type with constructor that needs to register the constructor's dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

I have two projects when the first one runs he injects dependencies, when the second runs he injects some to himself aswell.
I have a class called "SchedulerImpl" in the first project that looks like this:

```
  public class SchedulerImpl: ISche
{
    private IScheduler _scheduler;
    private string _uniqueId { get; set; }
    private string _userId;

    public SchedulerImpl(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _scheduler = scheduler;
    }
```

as you can see the constructor takes IScheduler type.

in project #2 I am trying to inject "SchedulerImpl" class(which belongs to project #1) and I need to also inject the IScheduler that the constructor injects, any ideas on how to do that?
I was looking at the documentation but it is too damn confusing.. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `ISche` a typo? Are you just trying to inject one implementation of `IScheduler` into another?

Comment: nope, after 3 hours the moment I post the question I manage to do it lol, will post answer now

Comment: maybe you know if theres a way to get Quartz existing instace from another project? the same instance as in the 1st# project?

Comment: Projects don't "run". If you register all the dependencies on startup, including an `IScheduler` instance then when you resolve an `ISche` the container will resolve the `IScheduler` for you and inject it into the constructor. You shouldn't need to do this manually.

Comment: It can be helpful to write a unit test to ensure that the container can resolve what it's supposed to resolve and injecting what you expect it to inject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register the `IScheduler`, e.g. as a singleton:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(QuartzInstance.Instance).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

and then the class that uses it:

```
builder.RegisterType<SchedulerImp>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

and let the container resolve them for you. You shouldn't need to do this manually unless there are specific things you need to pass to the constructor that can't be resolved.

If you have two projects and need each to register a bunch of classes or singletons with the container, use a `Module` in Autofac.

Comment: Sorry its hard for me to understand, "builder.Register(QuartzInstance.Instance).AsImplementedInterfaces();" is invalid because Register excpects a function, why is :
builder.Register(c => new SchedulerImpl(QuartzInstance.Instance)).As<ISche>();
not good?

Comment: Sorry, corrected, I meant `RegisterInstance` for a singleton. See https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html

Comment: This approach is more flexible: it doesn't tie the lifetimes of the two classes and it doesn't rely on a specific constructor for the `SchedulerImp` class. e.g. if you later make both classes transient (per-http request, say) or add another dependency to `SchedulerImp`.

Answer (score 1):

the Container should look like this

builder.Register(c => new SchedulerImpl(QuartzInstance.Instance)).As();

where

> SchedulerImpl

is the class with the constructor you want to inject,

> QuartzInstance.Instance

is the field that gets injected into the constructor,
and

> ISche

is the interface that SchedulerImpl implements